# How do I highlight a item in a dynamically created menu?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I've got PHP to create a menu based on the number of rows in a mysql database.

This is the PHP line:

```
print "<a href='diensten2.php?id={$row2['blog_id']}'>{$row2['navigatie']}</a>";
```

So every menu item links to a new dynamic page with the same menu. But I would like the selected menu item to be a different color (highlighted). I've tried a few things with javascript and PHP, but I need some help here, cause my knowledge is too limited i guess.

Could anyone put me in the right direction?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass the same variable via the url - you could try doing something like this -

```
<a href='diensten2.php?id={<?php echo $row2['blog_id'] ?>}' <?php if($_GET['id'] == $row['blog_id']) { ?>class='active'<?php } ?>>{<?php echo $row2['navigatie'] ?>}</a>;
```

The put all these links in a common include file. Also add a css code to highlight the .active class.

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to highlight the URL, which links to the page with an ID equal to the specified row['blog_id'], you would have to check each dynamic link, and assign a highlight class to it, maybe something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] == $row2["blog_id"])
    print "<a href='diensten2.php?id={$row2['blog_id']}' class=\"highlighted\">{$row2['navigatie']}</a>";

else
    print "<a href='diensten2.php?id={$row2['blog_id']}'>{$row2['navigatie']}</a>";
```

Comment: Mihir's solution follows the same idea, but with a little less code.

Comment: @RomiHalasz - thanks :) i didnt notice your post at the start :)